# Scala recursion: return vs if/else control

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm working through "Scala for the Impatient" and one of the exercises asks to write a function that computes `x^n` (by the method of [repeated squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)) without using the `return` keyword. My first thought was as follows:

```
def power(x: Double, n: Int): Double = {
    if(n > 0) {
        if (n % 2 != 0)  x * power(x, n-1) // adding a return works!
        else power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2) // adding a return works!
    }
    if(n < 0) 1/power(x, -n)               // adding a return works!
    else 1.0                               // adding a return works!
}
```

This doesn't work, however! What does work, is adding returns to each of the cases. What also works is the following:

```
def power(x: Double, n: Int): Double = {
    if(n > 0) {
        if (n % 2 != 0)  x * power(x, n-1)
        else power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)
    }
    else if(n < 0) 1/power(x, -n) 
    else 1.0
}
```

Why is my first attempt invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `n > 0` then `n < 0` is false so that `else 1.0` is executed.
So `1.0` should not be executed if `n > 0`.

```
if(n > 0) {
    if (n % 2 != 0)  x * power(x, n-1)
    else power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)
}
else if(n < 0) 1/power(x, -n)
else 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Note in the first example, the first `if` is vacuous in that it has no effect in the overall computation of `power`, as it does not relate with the other `if-else` expression(s) in the main body: the value from the last `if-else` is returned.

As a side note, in Scala `if-else` is an expression and as such *delivers* a (typed) value.

Consider functions `f` and `g`, as follows,

```
def f() = if (1==2) "whow!"
f: ()Any

def g() = if (1==2) "whow!" else "ok!"
f: ()String
```

Note the inferred return types. In function `f` the `else` part (not declared) is assumed to return a `Unit` type. Hence a *compatible* type between `Unit` and `String` in this case is `Any`.

This is in contrast with function `g` where the type is just `String`.